# Sublime Text 2 recognize underscore templates as HTML

Tags: underscore.js, sublimetext

So, i'm using underscore.js templates, in which i have to put my html template inside a script tag, like this

```
<script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">
    <img src="{{ photo }}" alt="{{ name }}" />
    <h1>{{ name }}<span>{{ type }}</span></h1>
    <div>{{ address }}</div>
    <dl>
        <dt>Tel:</dt><dd>{{ tel }}</dd>
        <dt>Email:</dt><dd><a href="mailto:{{ email }}">{{ email }}</a></dd>
    </dl>
</script>
```

but sublime text 2 is evaluating the code inside as regular js, how can i change that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have filed this as a bug with ST, so that all users may enjoy this fix in a future version: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/453232-/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. Go to `"Browse Packages"` in the menu (where the menu item is depends on your platform).
2. Open up `HTML/HTML.tmLanguage`
3. Change this line (line 286 in my `HTML.tmLanguage`):

   `<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)</string>`

   to this:

   `<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?!.*type=["']text/template['"])</string>`

Now any script tags with `type="text/template"` or `type='text/template'` will render as html and not javascript.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Was dying to use zencoding and tag-matches on heavy underscore templates.

Comment: God bless you, RegExp superhero.

Comment: And if you want this to work for "text/html" as well:
`<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?!.*type=["']text/(template|html)['"])</string>`

Comment: I did this and it works better but still doesn't close tag with the right tag though.  

(cmd+shift+i doesn't work.)

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yeah, but the file is in a zipped file in a different directory.  Look for the file `HTML.sublime-package` open it with winrar or something and get the file mentioned in the answer, mod it and put it back.

Comment: @PAEz I can't find HTML.sublime-package. Is the "different directory" the same for everyone? Which directory?

Comment: That, sir, was awesome.

Comment: this doesn't work for <script type="text/ng-template"></script>

Comment: The Sublime linter html tidy showed the warning, "Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here" The only way I was able to remove this error was to add "ignore_match": [
                    ".*not allowed here"
                ] to my htmltidy user settings. Does anyone know of a better solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

Because modifying built-in packages isn't exactly easy, safe, or portable (especially in ST3), I split out [Matt York's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886848/759780) change into its own package.

It is available via Package Control, and supports both Sublime Text 2 and 3 on all platforms.

[HTML Underscore Syntax](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML%20Underscore%20Syntax)

Comment: Just installed it on a fresh machine. Works perfectly in Sublime 3. Easier than editing the file. Thanks John!

Answer (score 3):

**For those of us using Sublime Text 3**

I thought I'd consolidate the information into something easier to find, since none of the answers or comments directly gave me the solution I needed. Matt York's answer is *mostly* correct, but Shane N's solution is a bit more flexible:

`<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?!.*type=["']text/(temp‌​late|html)['"])</string>`

You can find *HTML.sublime-package* inside `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages`, as mentioned by PAEz.

**Instructions**

1. Extract *HTML.sublime-package*'s contents like any normal zip file
2. Inside the new /HTML directory you just created, open HTML.tmLanguage and modify the line mentioned above (probably line 286)

   1. It should come right after `<key>begin</key>`
3. Save your changes, then add the /HTML directory that *HTML.tmLanguage* lives in to a new zip file
4. Delete the old *HTML.sublime-package* file
5. Change the filetype from `.zip` to `.sublime-package` (make sure Sublime isn't running while you do this)
6. You should now be good to go - fire up Sublime and check out your awesome newly-highlighted templates!

Comment: To do this for OS X, you'll first have to right-click on the ST3 application and choose "Show Package Contents," then navigate to Contents/MacOS/Packages/HTML.sublime-package

Answer (score 1):

For those of us using Sublime Text 3 use the plugin "PackageResourceViewer" to edit HTML.sublime-package

[PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)